# get non-matching line numbers python

Tags: python, enumerate

Hi I wrote a simple code in python to do the following:

I have two files summarizing genomic data. The first file has the names of loci I want to get rid of, it looks something like this

File_1:

```
R000002
R000003
R000006
```

The second file has the names and position of all my loci and looks like this:

File_2:

```
R000001 1
R000001 2
R000001 3
R000002 10
R000002 2
R000002 3
R000003 20
R000003 3
R000004 1
R000004 20
R000004 4
R000005 2
R000005 3
R000006 10
R000006 11
R000006 123
```

What I wish to do is get all the corresponding line numbers of loci from File2 that are not in File1, so the end result should look like this:

Result:

```
1
2
3
9
10
11
12
13
```

I wrote the following simple code and it gets the job done

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import sys

File1 = sys.argv[1]
File2 = sys.argv[2]

F1 = open(File1).readlines()
F2 = open(File2).readlines()
F3 = open(File2 + '.np', 'w')
Loci = []

for line in F1:
        Loci.append(line.strip())

for x, y in enumerate(F2):
        y2 = y.strip().split()
        if y2[0] not in Loci:
                F3.write(str(x+1) + '\n')
```

However when I run this on my real data set where the first file has 58470 lines and the second file has 12881010 lines it seems to take forever. I am guessing that the bottleneck is in the

```
if y2[0] not in Loci:
```

part where the code has to search through the whole of File_2 repeatedly but I have not been able to find a speedier solution.

Can anybody help me out and show a more pythonic way of doing things.

Thanks in advance

Comment: are your files ordered?

Comment: yes they are both ordered. However only some of the loci in File2 are in File_1 and File1 does not go sequentially. Meaning in File_1 you can jump from R000123 to R000255.

Comment: For starters you could make `Loci` into a `set` instead of a `list`.  That would certainly improve lookup time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's some slightly more Pythonic code that doesn't care if your files are ordered. I'd prefer to just print everything out and redirect it to a file `./myscript.py > outfile.txt`, but you could also pass in another filename and write to that.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

ignore_f = sys.argv[1]
loci_f = sys.argv[2]

with open(ignore_f) as f:
    ignore = set(x.strip() for x in f)

with open(loci_f) as f:
    for n, line in enumerate(f, start=1):
        if line.split()[0] not in ignore:
            print n
```

Searching for something in a list is O(n), while it takes only O(1) for a set. If order doesn't matter and you have unique things, use a `set` over a list. While this isn't optimal, it should be O(n) instead of O(n × m) like your code.

You're also not closing your files, which when reading from isn't that big of a deal, but when writing it is. I use context managers (`with`) so Python does that for me.

Style-wise, *use descriptive variable names*. and avoid `UpperCase` names, those are typically used for classes (see [PEP-8](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)).

If your files are ordered, you can step through them together, ignoring lines where the loci names are the same, then when they differ, take another step in your ignore file and recheck.

Answer (score 0):

To make the searching for matches more efficient you can simply use a `set` instead of `list`:

```
Loci = set()

for line in F1:
    Loci.add(line.strip())
```

The rest should work the same, but faster.

Even more efficient would be to walk down the files in a sort of lockstep, since they're both sorted, but that will require more code and maybe isn't necessary.